# How does enable client validation works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

When we write

```
 <appSettings>
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
```

What changes occur under the hood?

I expect that it adds functions to the events of our form elements.

Answer (score 1):

In a nut shell, it uses Javascript. Each element is decorated with data attributes indicating the type of validation to perform. When a form is submitted, the javascript is fired and it runs all elements that are marked for validation through a validator.

As usual, the same validation is then performed again on the server.

Comment: the javascript is fired when it's submitted that means it was associated with the submit event (but when association is done ?), but it's not only with submit, it works with focusout,click,keyup

Answer (score 1):

Refer this (very good article): [Unobtrusive Client Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

Some extracts from the same:

In MVC 3, we have a single flag to turn on unobtrusive JavaScript mode, which enables both unobtrusive Ajax and unobtrusive client validation. Unobtrusive JavaScript mode is turned off by default for backward compatibility with projects upgraded from MVC 1.0 and MVC 2. However, we have turned it on in the MVC 3 project template, so new projects will begin using the unobtrusive JavaScript support by default. Additionally, you will need to enable client side validation (which remains off by default).

We’ve replaced the JSON with HTML 5-compatible attributes which describe the validators to be attached to the input fields. We’ve also attached some HTML attributes to the validation message spans so that they can be related to the input field they’re attached to.

```
<label for="FirstName">FirstName</label>
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```